GraphQL query permissions with federated schema from different GraphQL microservices
I'm reading about schema stitching/federation and came across the example in the link:
extend type Reservation @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID! @external
  userId: ID! @external
  user: User @requires(fields: "userId")
}

They have 1 microservice exposing a GQL schema for reservations and 1 microservice exposing a schema for users and are merging the 2 into one schema.
Functionality-wise it makes sense, when you're viewing a reservation and want to get the user associated with the post the proxy automatically queries the users service with the ID(s) from the Reservation(s).
API design-wise, doesn't this mean that as part of the unified schema you must expose to the internet an API that allows users to query arbitrary IDs and thus get all the user metadata in your DB?
In a more "traditional" API design where only 1 API service is exposing itself to clients, I would just write a reservations endpoint that could query a user service on its own without having to expose that user service to the client API. I have full control over what I expose to the client and it doesn't depend on the implementation details of whatever "microservice architecture" I chose to use.
How is this exposing-microservices-to-the-client pattern that I'm seeing in Apollo/Chillicream/Guild's product marketing pages good API design, even for this supposedly trivial example?
